# PHP/Mysql: 2 selects from same table in one query

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

This is how my table looks like:

```
id | name | value
-----------------
 1 | user1|  1
 2 | user2|  1
 3 | user3|  3
 4 | user4|  8
 5 | user5|  6
 6 | user7|  4
 7 | user8|  9
 8 | user9|  2
```

What I want to do is to select all the other users, in one query, who's value is user1's value lower than it's value plus 3, higher than it's value minus 3 or equal to it's value.

Something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE value<'4' OR value>'-2'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['name'].'<br/>';
    }
```

The problem is that users1's value can vary every time the query is run.

Comment: its not possible with single query...
first you write query to fetch user1 value
e.g. select value fron table where name='user1'


then create 2 variables for upper and lower values
$upper = user1 value +3
$lower = user1 value  OR $lower = user1 value -3

and use BETWEEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for lame names, but this should work:

**NOTE: I named table with your data as "st".**

```
SELECT b.user, a.value as "user1val", b.value as "otheruservalue" FROM st as a
      join st as b
      on a.user = "user1" and a.user != b.user
 where
    (b.value > (a.value - 3)) and (b.value < (a.value + 3))
```

We get unique pairs of user1's value and other user's value by joining same table. After that we just do some simple comparison to filter rows with suitable values.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't actually knew how to use the join function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `value` FROM `users` WHERE id='1'"));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE value<'".$user1['value']."+3' OR value>'".$user1['value']."-3'");
```

Comment: Sidenote: OP is using `mysqli_*` functions and not `mysql_*`

Comment: `The problem is that users1's value can vary every time the query is run.`

Comment: I'm not :). But he'll get the idea.

Comment: If you get downvoted, it will `not` have come from me, so don't be surprised if you do. @OfirH - *Just saying* ;-) Plus, it's bad practice using deprecated functions.

Comment: @YellowBird vary how? in the while loop? If so put it inside the while.

Answer (score 0):

Or nested queries :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from `users` where `value` < (select `value` from `users` where `name`='user1')+3 OR `value` > (select `value` from `users` where `name`='user1')-3");
```

Comment: I would recommend here to use the Object Oriented method PDO to access the database. As it's not the subject, and StackOverflow is very hermetic to any advices which is not an answer I will only notice it in this comment. However it's a very much mighter, easier and securised way to connect and request most of the databases type nowadays.